# What's the linguistic term for the words used when addressing someone?

Tags: terminology

What is the linguistic term for words like sir, mam, miss, pal, bro, dude, buddy, son, mom/mum, dad etc.?

Although I understand that there is a fair degree of overlap, I'm not looking for the term "title". Titles are used *with* the addressee's name. I'm specifically looking for the term for the words used *without* (instead of) the addressee's name.

Comment: If they're being used in direct address (e.g: _Hi, Mom. Sir, your fly is unzipped. Wassup, Bro?_) then they're called ***vocatives***. This was a case in Latin, with a special ending (in any Latin prayer, the word _Domine_ 'O Lord', with an **-e** suffix, is in the vocative case: _Domine non sum dignus_ 'O Lord I am not worthy'.

Comment: @jlawler: +1 and why not make that an Answer? Detail: generally only words of the second declension masculine have a vocative ending that was different from the nominative. But you probably know that. In Greek, there are slightly more vocative markers.

Comment: Detail: of course. That's why I used a 2nd declension noun as an example. As for answer making, it's more work for nothing. Why bother?

Comment: I would call it "address".

Comment: id call it "Terms of Recognition"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Term of address' might be one way of referring to such expressions.
I believe 'honorific' denotes both the Mr/Mrs type and the sir type. However this may not include less formal terms like bro etc.

Along the same lines as jlawler, it seems that the noun 'vocative' can be applied to these kinds of words as well.